# If three men pre-arranged to sit down and eat together over a video-chat, is there any reason they shouldn't have a zimun?

Tags: internet, technology, bentching, zimun

I learned that if two groups were eating in two different rooms but even one person could see someone in the other room, then they could have one zimun (I thought this was in Masechet Brachot, but I can't find it). Could this extend to video-chat?

Comment: As always, for practical matters, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Answer (score 4):

Voice over the internet is halachically considered an echo.
Brachot and prayer can not be said over the internet, nor can you listen to a shofar blast over the phone etc. (source  http://www.chaburas.org/ramkol.html )

That would be a reason to not do a mizuman over video-chat.

As to the question of if you are "allowed" to do a mezuman over an echo / video chat, I am not sure.  [See here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5862/amen-on-the-telephone) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/amen-for-recorded-brochos) for the debate.

Comment: I would clarify that since the essence of a zimun is for one person to include the others of the group (be motzi them), avi's echo would preclude them from forming a zimun.

Comment: Where do you get the "VoIP is echo" bit from?

Comment: Two places.. one it is. What you hear over voip is not a person's voice, but rather another material giving the voice over.  Secondly, its an old halachic ruling that microphones count as halachic echos.  Void is done via a microphone on one end, and a speaker on the other.

Comment: -1. IIRC, some *Poskim* (inlcuding the Tzitz Eliezer and Minchas Elazar, according to [this answer and the comments thereon](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8995/1059)) permit *Mikra Megillah* via telephone, as well as participating in a Siyyum in order to partake in a Seudat Mitzvah. Why should VoIP be any different than telephone?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Only for sick people who can't otherwise hear the megillah.  Also, if you read other positions of the Tzzit Eliezer and Minchas Elazar you will find many inconsitancies on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Tzitz Eliezer, one can fulfill the mitzvot of reading the Torah, blowing the shofar, and hearing the megillah via telephone or radio. See his famous tshuva (8:11) http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14507&st=&pgnum=53

His permission is if there is no other way *or* in a case (such as a large hospital) where it is not practical to accomplish the mitzvah for a lot of people without using  a microphone. So I would suggest that perhaps in this case of eating together online, since there is no other way to accomplish the mitzvah except via microphone, then it would be permitted.

Comment: blowing the shofar? really?

Comment: Apparently, we have contradictory teshuvahs from the Tzitz Eliezer: http://koltorah.org/ravj/The%20Parameters%20of%20Kol%20Isha.htm

Comment: Famous as that teshuva is, it seems like its not correct, even according to the Tzitz! "Despite these view, Rav Yoseif brings in the view of the Tzitz Eliezer (4:26) who rules that the voice heard through the microphone is not the voice of a human, but rather that voice is gone and these noises are new, machine-generated sounds that cannot help one fulfill his obligation to hear Megilla"

Comment: All I can say is read the tshuva itself (which is why I provided the link) as opposed to english summaries of other tshuvas.

Comment: The Tzitz Eliezer refers to his view in 4:26 in the tshuva I listed (section 2), and I think he basically resolves that since many poskim (prominent among them the Minchas Elazar) permit listening over the telephone, so in a place of need or if there is no other way, then he (the Tzitz Eliezer) would permit it also, which is precisely the way I used his tshuva in my response above -- where there is no other way to accomplish the mitzvah then "perhaps" one could rely on the Tzitz Eliezer (and Minchas Elazar)

Comment: In any case, as is made clear in the tshuva I attached, enough significant poskim allow ram kol over radio or telephone that any answer to this question which doesn't recognize their views is, I think, flawed.

Comment: There is always a way to fulfill Birkat Hamazon without microphone. Everyone can just say it to themselves.